# property not found when trying to print list value using jstl for each loop using index

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to print the list value using jstl for each loop as shown below.

```
<c:forEach var="listitems" varStatus="count" items="${list}">
    <c:if test="${count.index > 0}">
            <c:out value="${listitems[count.index]}"></c:out>
    </c:if>
```

Here the list contains elements of string type.When i am using count.index it is saying property 0 not found on type string .

Comment: @SMA i have added the code.Could you please help if possible,thanks in advance

Comment: I got the answer, if i am using index i shouldnt be using var attribute of c:foreach tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`var` attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) to reference the current item.

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <c:out value="${item}" />
</c:forEach>
```